# How can I convert an Integer to month name in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, gremlin

I get an integer and I need to convert to a month names in current locales:

Example for locale en-us:
1 -> January
2 -> February

sample example of my code in gremlin :

```
.....groupBy{[it[3], it[2].getMonth()]}{it[1]}{it.sum()}.cap().scatter().transform{[Name:it.key,Tx:it.value]}
```

here I get as :

```
==>{Name=[ABC, 7], Tx=1750.0}
```

i want the month integer in name format .

I tried ,

`it[2].getMonth().toString() and also as cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) etc`. But no suceess.

Comment: `Replace("Thanks", "Acceptance")`.... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert a month integer to a String, you can do:

```
String month = new java.text.DateFormatSymbols().months[ 4 ]

assert month == 'May'
```

Comment: new java.text.DateFormatSymbols().months[it[2].getMonth()]...              it's working . thanx.

Comment: how to display the above in this month year format like : July 12, Aug 13 etc ?

Comment: http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#format(java.lang.String)

Comment: I tried with this but again month in integer way is displayed.                    {new Date(it.getProperty("date")).format('MM yy')}           it shows as 02 12 , 03 12 ...month name again back to integer form. :(

Comment: {new Date(it.getProperty("date")).format('MMM yy')} .. sorry my bad. thanks . :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider these three ways of doing that, I hope these will help you.

1)you can do as below by giving month as integer

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
public String getMonth(int month) {
return new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month-1];
}
```

2)you can do as below by giving date

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "LLLL", Locale.getDefault() );
dateFormat.format( date );
```

3)Using SimpleDateFormat.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public String formatMonth(String month) {
SimpleDateFormat monthParse = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
SimpleDateFormat monthDisplay = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
return monthDisplay.format(monthParse.parse(month));
}
formatMonth("2"); //Result: February
```

Comment: In Groovy, your option #3 can be simplified to `String formatMonth( int month ) { Date.parse( 'MM', "$month" ).format( 'MMMM' ) }`

Comment: thanx for these diff. techniques.